# Delete specific AppData subfolder file in userprofile (windows 10)

Tags: batch-file

I need some advice on my plan to create a script file to delete certain files (log files( in the AppData subfolder. the logs is auto generated daily and save in their AppData folder

My plan is:

1. only to delete a log files inside the log folder that the age more than 10days and remain the new logs inside the folder.

My problem is, there are some folder before the logs folder generated different on each customer. Here the example of 2 sample customer that using the application. The bold subfolder is auto generated folder by system and on each user, it create a random subfolder name except for the last Folder Logs. The logs files that I want to create a script to delete is reside in the Logs folder.

C:\Users\zulhadi\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\**TOHH10RY.RPR\1TK3RWZA.7LL**\tmov..tion_c53c7abfec4c3d4d_0001.000c_3bf64a70373000ba\Logs

C:\Users\ainul\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\**ALR6MXVO.1Q5\EXHY50X4.TDT**\tmov..tion_c53c7abfec4c3d4d_0001.000c_3bf64a70373000ba\Logs

My question is:

Any idea how can I create a script that delete the logs files in the logs folder if the situation like below as explain. I'm not a very computer background and not very familiar about scripting but do have see some video/tutorial over internet on this basic of scripting of deleting the folder in windows 10.

Comment: Finding the `logs` directories is no problem. The issue is which files to delete. Applying a rule like `delete if older than 10 days` is applied, then there would ne no log data left except that that was generated in the last 10 days. The directories for customers who had generated no logs in the last 10 days would become empty. Is this intended? Could you perhaps keep only the last 10 or 20 or 50 log files created in each `logs` directory? Would that suit your purpose?

Comment: hi @Magoo, tqvm for your input & suggestion. Ya, i think your input on keep some of amount of logs files is meet the purpose. My main attention, just only want to keep only newest generated logs inside that logs folder.

Comment: Something like this one line batch file should work based upon your provided information: ```@For /D %%G In ("%LocalAppData%\Apps\2.0\*") Do @For /D %%H In ("%%G\*") Do @For /F "Skip=10 Delims=" %%I In ('Dir "%%H\tmov..tion_c53c7abfec4c3d4d_0001.000c_3bf64a70373000ba\Logs\*.log" /A:-D /B /O:-D 2^>NUL') Do @Del /A /F "%%I"```

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following setting for the source directory is a name
rem that I use for testing and deliberately includes spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"

FOR /d /r "%sourcedir%" %%b IN (*) DO IF /i "%%~nxb"=="logs" (
 rem for each logs directory found, get a list of the .log files
 rem sorted in reverse-date order. Skip the first 10 (newest) and delete the rest
 FOR /f "skip=10delims=" %%e IN ('dir /b /a-d /o-d "%%b\*.log" 2^>nul') DO ECHO DEL "%%b\%%e"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.

The required DEL commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO DEL` to `DEL` to actually delete the files.

Perform a recursive listing of the directorynames starting at the chosen `sourcedir` (See `for /?` from the prompt for documentation) and select only those with a "leafname" (final element of the full directoryname) of `logs`. The full directoryname found is in `%%b`.

With each such directoryname, perform a directory list of the `*.log` files using `dir` producing names-only (/b) and no directorynames (/a-d) in order of reverse-date (/o-d) - see `dir/?` from the prompt for documentation.

We need the full name reported by `dir`, so `delims` is set to *nothing*, and we need to skip the first 10 lines of the report since we wish to retain the latest 10 files which are the first 10 lines returned as the report is sorted in reverse-date order.

The `2^>nul` suppresses the error report generated by `dir` should there be no matching filenames in the directory.  The caret is used as an "escape" character to tell `cmd` that the `>` redirector forms part of the `dir` command, not the `for`.

Comment: Hi @Magoo, thank. thank for your script input.. i need to go through back to understand as i'm not very familiar with this scripting...hehe